# JDBC template update query error

Tags: java, mysql, spring-mvc, jdbc

I am trying to update mysql DB with jdbc template update query in Spring

**My Query**

```
String query = "update request set regions=?, requesttype=?, requestorigin=?, lineofbusiness=?, destinationenvironment=?, release=?, workrequest=?,"
                    + " spmid=?, requestingteam=? where requestid="+request.getRequestId()+";"; 
            System.out.println(query);
            Object[] params = {request.getRegions(), request.getRequestType(), request.getRequestOrigin(),
                    request.getLineOfBusiness(),
                    request.getDestinationEnvironment(),
                    request.getReleaseValue(), request.getWorkRequest(),
                    request.getSpmId(), request.getRequestingTeam()
                     };
            int[] types = { Types.VARCHAR, Types.VARCHAR, Types.VARCHAR, Types.VARCHAR,
                    Types.VARCHAR, Types.VARCHAR, Types.VARCHAR, Types.VARCHAR,
                    Types.VARCHAR };
            return jdbcTemplate.update(query, params, types);
```

When i run this query it shows Mysql Grammar error. I couldnt able to find
where i went wrong.

**Stack Trace**

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/TDM] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [update request set regions=?, requesttype=?, requestorigin=?, lineofbusiness=?, destinationenvironment=?, release=?, workrequest=?, spmid=?, requestingteam=? where requestid=319;]; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'release='Search and Load', workrequest='zxZ', spmid='zxXZxZ', requestingteam='Se' at line 1] with root cause
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'release='Search and Load', workrequest='zxZ', spmid='zxXZxZ', requestingteam='Se' at line 1
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:936)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2941)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1623)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1715)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3249)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1268)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1541)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1455)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1440)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$2.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:873)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$2.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:866)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:629)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:866)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:927)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:932)
    at org.verizon.tdm.dao.impl.RequestDaoImpl.updateRequest(RequestDaoImpl.java:62)
    at org.verizon.tdm.service.impl.RequestServiceImpl.updateRequestDetails(RequestServiceImpl.java:27)
    at org.verizon.tdm.controller.RequestDetailsController.saveRequestAjaxPage(RequestDetailsController.java:53)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:111)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:806)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:729)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:301)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1015)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:652)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1575)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1533)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**My Schema**

```
***Field    Type    Null    Key Default Extra***
requestid   int(11) NO  PRI NULL    auto_increment
regions varchar(250)    YES     NULL    
requesttype varchar(95) YES     NULL    
requestorigin   varchar(25) YES     NULL    
lineofbusiness  varchar(250)    YES     NULL    
destinationenvironment  varchar(250)    YES     NULL    
release varchar(250)    YES     NULL    
workrequest varchar(250)    YES     NULL    
spmid   varchar(250)    YES     NULL    
requestingteam  varchar(250)    YES     NULL    
datapoints  varchar(500)    YES     NULL    
status  enum('SUBMITTED','SERVICED','DRAFT','INPROGRESS','FAILED')  YES     NULL
```

Comment: Answer:

I am not very good at DB.. Actually the column release is a keyword in Mysql.. Thats why it thrown exception.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on this error message:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'release='Search and Load', workrequest='zxZ', spmid='zxXZxZ', requestingteam='Se' at line 1

The problem seems to be with the `release` column.
Are you sure the column exists? (Correct spelling, correct upper/lower case in the name.)

**UPDATE**

As it turns out, `release` is a keyword in MySQL.
You need to quote that field using backticks, like this:

```
String query = "update request set regions=?, `release`=?, workrequest=?,"
```

---

Not related to your problem,
but just like you inject the values to set with ? parameters, do the same for `request.getRequestId()` in the condition, instead of string concatenation. That way it will be injected in a type safe way.

That is, the end of the SQL string should look like:

```
... where requestid= ?
```

and add `request.getRequestId()` in the parameters just like the other values that you set, in `params` and `types`.

Answer (score 2):

Check whether by putting quotes, does it solve the problem?

```
"update `request` set `regions`=?, `requesttype`=?, `requestorigin`=?, `lineofbusiness`=?, `destinationenvironment`=?, `release`=?, `workrequest`=?,"
                    + " `spmid`=?, `requestingteam`=? where `requestid`="
```

Comment: Hey it will work :) but i am sorry i cant accept two answers.. anyways the actual reason is due to the usage of a keyword as column name

Comment: no problem, you could upvote answer :). Good that you have solved your problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you also parameterize the requestId in your query? Assuming the requestId is of type INTEGER, the code can be re-written to this:

```
String query = "update request set regions=?, requesttype=?, requestorigin=?, lineofbusiness=?, destinationenvironment=?, release=?, workrequest=?,"
                    + " spmid=?, requestingteam=? where requestid=?"; 
System.out.println(query);
Object[] params = {request.getRegions(), request.getRequestType(), request.getRequestOrigin(),
        request.getLineOfBusiness(),
        request.getDestinationEnvironment(),
        request.getReleaseValue(), request.getWorkRequest(),
        request.getSpmId(), request.getRequestingTeam(),
         request.getRequestId()};
int[] types = { Types.VARCHAR, Types.VARCHAR, Types.VARCHAR, Types.VARCHAR,
        Types.VARCHAR, Types.VARCHAR, Types.VARCHAR, Types.VARCHAR,
        Types.VARCHAR, Types.INTEGER };
return jdbcTemplate.update(query, params, types);
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
request.getSpmId(), request.getRequestingTeam(),
```

you are placing a comma at the end of the Object array.

Comment: No, i have one more element to add after request.getRequestingTeam()

Comment: but you are already giving 9 values for 9 placeholders. Am I right?

Comment: thats  a good catch.. but that is not a problem.. i have updated my code based on janos's suggestion.. still it throws exception

Comment: Yeah I got it remove the concatenated double quoted semicolon ";" at last in query and then try it.

Comment: Have you tried update(String query,Object[] params) version?